# IBM Worklight 6.1 Studio installation fails in Eclipse Kepler & Juno?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

while Installing IBM Worklight V6.1.0 for Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) and Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1), I am getting Errors

Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/content.xml.

Can any one Help me.

Comment: Where do you try to install? Windows? Mac? Linux? Did you try in all three and it failed in all three?

Comment: I tried to Install on Windows Server 2008 and Linux RHEL 6 Machines, But in these two Machines it's not Supporting to Install IBM Worklight 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried installing Worklight 6.1.0.1 from Eclipse Marketplace, using a clean Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, 4.3.1. I am on Windows 7. It installed successfully.

- Try with a clean eclipse environment
- Make sure you are using the [Java EE Developer edition](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1) of Eclipse 4.3.1
- Check to ensure you have all of the correct system requirements here:
  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838

Also see [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888734/unable-to-install-plugin-ibm-worklight-developer-edition-v6-1-0-1-on-eclipse-kep).

Comment: Hi Barbara, You checked all 3 Files at a time or first Worklight Studio and next Remaining Two Files.

Comment: Vamsi, I selected all 3 features when installing. Can you tell me the steps you followed?

Comment: Hi Barbara, Due to proxy server i am unable to install it, Now i installed Successfully and started Development on Worklight v6.1.

Comment: glad to hear it Vamsi