# Unable to install plugin IBM Worklight Developer Edition V6.1.0.1 on Eclipse kepler 4.3.1, on 32 bit

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using eclipse kepler 32 bit. I am trying to install IBM Worklight Developer Edition V6.1.0.1 from market place. I am getting following error.

I tried running it as administrator. Also tried to append -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true at the ini file. but nothing worked out.

[image: Installing software has encountered a problem]

Comment: I don't think we can help you, according to the error, the repository is just offline

Answer (score 1):

It might have been an outage; it seems to be working now. I just installed successfully from Eclipse Marketplace. Try now and let us know if it still fails.

Also, make sure you are using the Java EE Developer edition of Eclipse 4.3.1:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1

And check all of the system requirements here to ensure you have the right environment:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838

Alternatively, you can download the [zip](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.1.0.1.zip) file and install from eclipse workbench as a local archive.

Comment: I tried to hit the URL http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.ibm.etools.webedit.xulrunner_1.0.0.v20140518_1358.jar. I am able to download it.

Comment: The other URL http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.upgrader.plugin_1.0.0.00-20140516-2320.jar is taking lot of time to download. The internet speed is good here. But it is taking lot of time and getting timed out

Comment: To install, you should use the Eclipse Marketplace client from within your eclipse workbench (Help-> Eclipse Marketplace, then search for Worklight). You're not trying to install via the plugins directory you posted in the comments, are you?

Comment: You can find step by step install instructions and requirements here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/

Answer (score 0):

I tried connecting to american VPN, I was able to download the files quick. The plugin got installed without any issues.

Comment: glad to hear it. Please mark this answered. Thanks.